# Exponential distribution confidence interval

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

**Question:**

[image]

I think I mostly understand (a) and (b), but I don't understand (c).

**My Work:**

Asymptotically, $2\big[ \ell(\hat \lambda) - \ell(\lambda) \big] \sim \chi_1^2$, where $\hat \lambda = 1/\bar X$ is the MLE. The log-likelihood is

\begin{align*}
\ell(\lambda) &= n\log \lambda - \lambda \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i.
\end{align*}

We have the probability

\begin{align*}
P\big( 2\big[ \ell(\hat \lambda) - \ell(\lambda) \big] > 3.841 \big) \approx 0.95
\end{align*}

and we want to isolate $\lambda$ on the left. I get stuck when I try to do this. We have

\begin{align*}
2\big[ \ell(\hat \lambda) - \ell(\lambda) \big] &= 2\Big[ n\log(1/\bar X) - n - n\log \lambda + \lambda \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Big]
\end{align*}

At this point I'm stuck.

I don't know what deviance is. I *think* I'm supposed to make $T_1 = \bar X/\lambda \sim \text{Gamma}(n, 1/n)$ (using shape and scale) appear somewhere, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: This is very good.  The trick is to simply note that the likelihood ratio is a monotonic transformation of $\sum x_i$ or equivalently $\bar{x}$ which follows a gamma distribution, which you have done.  You could invert the cdf of the chi-square distribution referencing the observed likelihood ratio test statistic (an approximate test), or you could invert the cdf of the gamma distribution while referencing the observed $\bar{x}$ or as you have it, $\bar{x}/\lambda$.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson You mean I need to need to apply the change of variables formula to $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$? I don't get what you mean. I *think* I am looking for something like $n\bar X/\lambda - n\log \bar X/\lambda - n$, but I don't see how to make that appear.

Comment: Here's an example: the logarithm is a monotonic transformation.  If I apply this to a lognormal random variable, the result is a normally distributed random variable.  Likewise, if I exponentiate a normally distributed random variable I get a lognormal random variable.  The likelihood ratio is just another monotonic transformation, like $g=$exp$(\cdot)$ or $g=$log$(\cdot)$.  Rather than discussing the probability distribution of $g(\bar{X})$ you can discuss the probability distribution of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson Thanks for your help. I am preoccupied with another problem right now but I will come back and try to digest what you're saying. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps you are wanting to use the chi-square approximation to the likelihood ratio test statistic.  In that case you could simply write $\{\lambda: F_{\chi^2_1}(-2\text{log(LR)})>\alpha  \}$ where $-2\text{log(LR)}$ is your observed likelihood ratio test statistic and $F$ is the cdf of a chi-squared distribution.  It's not always easy to isolate the parameter like with a Wald test.  In practice you would numerically invert the CDF of the chi-square distribution to identify those hypotheses for $\lambda$ such that the likelihood ratio test does not reject at level $\alpha$.

Comment: Deviance is the difference in log likelihoods.

Comment: Try writing $P(q_{\alpha/2} < -2\text{log(LR)} < q_{1-\alpha/2})=1-\alpha$ and pivoting this like for a Wald interval so that $\lambda$ is isolated in the middle.  $q$ is the percentile of the $\chi^2_1$ distribution.